# Multiple boxplots in subplots with plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create a multiple boxplot app with subplots from plotly that lets me know the evolution of a variable separated by different criteria.

My code looks like this:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

trace0 = go.Box(
    y=df[(df.tipo == 'n')]['p'],
    x=df[(df.tipo == 'n')]['m'], 
    name='N'
)

trace1 = go.Box(
    y=df[(df.tipo == 's')]['p'],
    x=df[(df.tipo == 's')]['m'], 
    name='S'
)


fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.append_trace(trace0, row = 1, col = 1)
fig.append_trace(trace1, row = 1, col = 2)

fig.show()
```

The output of this looks like:

[image]

What I am trying to get is something that would look like this, but for each subplot:

[image]

I do have two dummy variables that allow me to separate it in subplots.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

- you have implied what your data is,  have simulated data from this
- have use **plotly express** instead of **graph objects**
- core solution is add all of the traces associated with a figure to the required sub-plots. With you case of having box plots for value **N** and **S** in **topo** column means two traces need to be added to each sub-plot
- there are a few cleanup actions on **layout** and **traces** to make **xaxis** work as required and remove duplicates from legend

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.DataFrame({**{"month":np.tile(pd.date_range("1-jul-2020", freq="M", periods=12),20)[0:200],
                   "tipo":np.random.choice(["N","S"],200)},
                   **{f"var{v}":np.random.uniform(2,5,200) for v in range(8)}})

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=3, cols=3, subplot_titles=[c for c in df.columns if "var" in c]
)

for v in range(8):
    for t in px.box(df, x="month", y=f"var{v}", color="tipo").data:
        fig.add_trace(t, row=(v//3)+1, col=(v%3)+1)

# modifications needed to fix up display of sub-plots
fig.update_layout(
    boxmode="group", margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 20, "b": 0}
).update_traces(showlegend=False, selector=lambda t: "var0" not in t.hovertemplate)
```

[image]